# Would it be possible to open a website and then run JavaScript in it using Python?

Tags: javascript, python, console

I have been trying to open a website (using python), then run a JavaScript script on it.

I did the open the website part, but I haven't managed to get the JavaScript to run after the page loads.

```
import os
url='example.com'
jscode='alert(\'success\')'
os.system('start chrome.exe '+url+' javascript:'+jscode)
```

The code above is the best I can think of.

It opens the website but does not run the javascript.

I used `os.system()` because other methods have problems with chrome.

Comment: Chrome doesn't take a JavaScript argument like that. The best I can think of is to use some kind of automation tool (like AppleScript on MacOS) to tell the browser to open DevTool, and then send the JS to the console window.

Comment: You just can't do "the best you think of", you need at least to relate on some documentation, you can't at all just pass JS to be executed on any website

Comment: Selenium, Puppeteer and PhantomJs should be able to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

VBScript and batch together to open the site then enter keystrokes

'https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/Make+a+batch+file+that+opens+site+in+browser+and+enter+login+information' was very useful for developing this answer

```
'''
enclosed in '{}' means special characters

'~' or '{ENTER}' = [ENTER]
'^' = [CTRL]

multiple characters in the same list item are typed at the same time
'''

keyplan = ["^l","javascript:alert{(}'success'{)}","~"]

with open('temp.cmd','w') as f: pass
with open('temp.cmd', 'a') as f:
    #batch code section
    f.write(
     '@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then\n'
    +'@echo off\n'
    +'set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"\n')
    +'START CHROME "example.com"\n'
    +'timeout /t 10\n'
    )#the timeout is to give time for the page to load
    
    #log keys in plan
    for key in keyplan:
        f.write('%SendKeys% "'+key+'"\n')
    
    f.write('goto :EOF\n')
    f.write('@end\n')
    
    #VBScript section
    f.write('var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");\n')
    
    #send keys (runs on every '%SendKeys% "key")
    f.write('WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));\n')
os.system("temp.cmd")
```

After writing this I have realized that `import pynput` is a method that would not involve `os.system`.